# Unable to load SQL query in R

Tags: sql, r, syntax-error

I'm getting the following error despite being able to run my SQL query in DBeaver:

```
Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DSG09272"
LINE 259: where t.event_name in ('DSG09272', 'DSG10012', 'DSG10042','D...
```

For context I'm using the funciton dbGetQuery in R.  For some reason I'm getting a syntax error in my where statement But I don't see any errors.

```
where c.acct_id in (
select acct_id 
from database t 
where t.event_name in ('DSG09272', 'DSG10012', 'DSG10042','DSG10132','DSG10152','DSG10272','DSG10292','DSG10312','DSG11022','DSG11082','DSG11102','DSG11122','DSG11152','DSG11232','DSG11252','DSG11282',              'DSG12012','DSG12042','DSG12092','DSG12132','DSG12232','DSG12292','DSG01073','DSG01103','DSG01123','DSG01163','DSG01193','DSG01213', 'DSG02012', 'DSG02013', 'DSG02113','DSG02213','DSG02263','DSG02283','DSG03043','DSG03063','DSG03093','DSG03113','DSG03193','DSG03213','DSG03243','DSG03273','DSG03313','DSG04083','DSG04133'
) and left(t.plan_event_name, 3) = 'DSF' and t.ticket_status = 'A' and t.comp_name = 'Not Comp'
group by 1)
```

I thought the code might be too long so I deleted a large portion that I commented out, but I still wasn't able to fix the issue.

Comment: Questions: What is your actual database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)?  Is your table really named `database`?  Does your database support the `LEFT` function?

Comment: My table isn't actually named database I just did that for some anonymity.  My database is hosted by redshift and uses PostgreSQL.  It does support joint I have multiple left joins and inner joins in my query and it does supports group by statements.  The query runs correctly in my SQL IDE.

Comment: Can you get any queries to complete via R? Just something basic like `select * from table limit 1`, then try `select * from table where event_name = 'DSG10012'`.

Comment: I'm able to do both of those queries in R.

Comment: I would just keep adding to the complexity of the query until you reach an error. Maybe a problem with a join or condition that may shine a light on the problem.

Comment: Maybe the line is too long. Try to reformat it

Comment: I tried deleting my where statement and then get a similar error earlier in the code: Error: Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'5691
)
order by cast(kore_primaryaccountnumber as int) asc -- coalesce(activitydate, completedon) desc
)
group by 1
order by cast(kore_primaryaccountnumber as int) asc) act on act.account_id = c.acct_id 
"
LINE 248: ...870','5606612','5614891','5615120','5631711','5685084','5691

Comment: _Assuming_ that the query does not actually begin with `where c.acct_id in (`, then I see nothing obviously wrong with this query. I wonder if the [tag:r] tag is extraneous, there's nothing here that suggests R is involved in the problem. What DBMS are you using? If [tag:r] is the culprit (meaning you can run this query in a regular DBMS tool such as `sqlite.exe` or `sqlcmd.exe`, whatever is appropriate for your OS), then please include how you are using R to conduct this query, including non-base packages (`DBI` vs `RODBC`), code, etc. Thanks!